# I get multiple errors, when I try to install all modules from a package.json file on my nginx webserver

Tags: nginx, npm, npm-install, package.json, nginx-config

I'm currently trying to configure my portfolio on a VPS using nginx and Putty.
Now I want to install all required modules for my backend, but I get this errors.
I have no idea what to do and would love to get some help.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /root/portfolio/server/node_modules/.staging/@types/webidl-conversions-b037bbf1/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -20
npm ERR! syscall open 
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/root/portfolio/server/node_modules/.staging/@types/webidl-conversions-b037bbf1/package.json'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/portfolio/server/npm-debug.log
```

To install all the modules, I went to my backend folder and typed 'npm install' in my Putty console.
Then it starts to download the modules and everything seems fine, until the errors pop up after a few seconds.
I also tried 'apt-get update' and 'apt-get upgrade', but it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
I had to update my node and npm, but not like usually with 'apt update', 'apt upgrade', 'apt install nodejs' or 'apt install npm'.
Instead I tried this:

> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
> nvm install 14.4.0

... and then it worked.
Hope this will help someone